# How to render a view & controller globally in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Ok, so I have a notifications controller similar to SO's. It shows up fine when I'm in the nofications#index page but doesn't show on any other view such as my home page.

Is there any way for me to render the notifications partial while still including it's controller gobally (have it show on any & every page)?

Thanks in advance

here's my notifications controller

---

```
class NotificationsController < ApplicationController
    def index
        @notifications = Notification.where('user_id = ?', current_user.id)
    end
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a before_filter in ApplicationController that grabs whatever notifications you want the user to see and puts them into say @notifications.  Then in your layout render the partial that displays them if @notifications has something in it.

```
class ApplicationController

  before_filter :load_notifications

  def load_notifications
    @notifications = Notification.where('user_id = ?', current_user.id)
  end

end
```

Then in say app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:

```
<% @notifications.each do |n| %>
  <%= n.message %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I don't think I'm completely understanding. I knew I would have to do something with the ApplicationController but how would you "grab" the notifications? I went ahead and pasted in my notifications controller above btw.. I'm also using "presenters" if that makes a difference.. @Philip

Comment: @Jon I think you should read more about MVC and RoR's implementation of the MVC design pattern. Controller actions are mapped to requests (URLs) via routes (`routes.rb`).

So if you have configured `Notifications#index` to be executed for requests matching `/notifications`, then you can't expect it to be executed for other requests.

In other words, typically only one controller/action is executed per request.

Comment: @PhilipHallstrom *slaps head* ofcourse, you meant as a method.. Should've been commonsense.. I've been working on this app for a while now so I'm kinda' sleep deprived. Thanks, it worked like a charm